# malloc_error_break breakpoint crash

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im using the following code to populate a nsmutablearray

```
_unique = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id obj in statusDateArray) {
    if (![_unique containsObject:obj]) {
        [_unique addObject:obj];
    }
}
```

But im getting the following error sometimes.

> malloc: *** error for object 0x15d86b120: pointer being freed was not
>   allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

why am I getting this error and how can i sort this out?

Comment: It might be crashing in that code, but there is nothing wrong with it.  I'm guessing you have a `weak` pointer involved somewhere...  Have you done what the error message mentioned?

Comment: i have not used weak pointers in my .h or .m file

Answer (score 0):

I think you set the property as weak or you have deallocate it or free it. (Check it out)

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.